# Why using the "momentary comoving reference frame" for energy-momentum tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to understand the so called “momentary commoving reference frame” (MCRF) used for the energy-moment tensor in GR.
Using the example of the suspension system of a car, each cubic element around a point of the spring has a stress tensor changing with time, as the car moves trough an off road way. The elements have different velocities because they vibrate due to the loads and elastic constant of the spring. Velocity * spring density = p (momentum per volume). $p_x, σ_{xx},σ_{yx}$ and $σ_{zx}$ form one of the lines of the 4x4 energy-moment tensor.
The importance of p and tensions in elasticity relates to the equation: $F_x = \frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \sigma_{yx}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \sigma_{zx}}{\partial z}$, where $F_x = \frac{\partial p_x}{\partial t}$.
Similar for the other axis.
It is not required that the elements are momentarily at rest to that (non relativistic) analysis.
I assume that MCRF is necessary in relativity because different speeds would require Lorentz transformation between the elements, and it must be avoided.

Comment: Claudio I'm not sure whether I understand your question... I'm not sure I completely understand your answer at the end either, but I have the feeling that it's correct. [Continued]

Comment: The stress-energy-momentum tensor embodies several quantities of classical mechanics (energy density, energy flux, momentum density, stress), which should turn out to be components in some specific coordinate system. The question is which coordinate system. The natural assumption is that they're the values measured by an observer at rest w.r.t. the volume element such quantities refer to. "Natural" because it seems the closest interpretation keeping an eye on the Newtonian balance laws for these quantities. Yet, this is partly an assumption. [Continued]

Comment: Equivalently, without bringing in coordinates, the sixteen quantities are defined as various parallel/orthogonal projections of the stress-energy-momentum tensor w.r.t. the 4-velocity of the volume element. Good references for this are Tolman's *Relativity, Thermodynamics and Cosmology* around § 37, and Eckart's [*The thermodynamics of irreversible processes. III. Relativistic theory of the simple fluid*](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.58.919)

Comment: ...oops just now realized that this was an old question...

Comment: Well, thanks for the comments. I didn't know Latex that time, and corrected now some equations...

Answer (score 1):

It is believed that the physical laws should have the same form independently of the coordinate system in which they are stated. Reason being that coordinates are just artefacts of the human mind. That means that you may choose a reference system where the physical relations are easier to be written.

A reference frame instantaneously at rest with an arbitrary reference frame is an inertial reference frame where you may apply the laws of SR (special relativity). Then via the tensor formalism you can extend the application to GR (general relativity).